# OpenEJB NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: junit, openejb

I have such dependencies in maven project. And use OpenEJB for test EJB beans

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>openejb-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${openejb-junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

My test for IReportService

```
    @RunWith(EJBContainerRunner.class)
    public class ReportFacadeBeanTest {

        @EJB
        private IReportService iReportService;

        @Test
        public void testPrintReport() throws Exception {
            Asserts.assertNotNull(iReportService);

    }
}
```

When I try run test I have error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.processApplicationExceptions(AnnotationDeployer.java:2873)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:2383)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:1819)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:360)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:403)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:971)
    at org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$Provider.createEJBContainer(OpenEjbContainer.java:364)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:77)
    at org.apache.openejb.junit.jee.statement.StartingStatement.before(StartingStatement.java:96)
    at org.apache.openejb.junit.jee.statement.DecoratingStatement.evaluate(DecoratingStatement.java:30)
    at org.apache.openejb.junit.jee.statement.DecoratingStatement.evaluate(DecoratingStatement.java:32)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource
    at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:176)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:80)
    ... 21 more
```

When I change scope all work fine =(

How run test with scope - provided? I dont' want use compile

Answer (score 0):

Well... if `net.sf.jasperreports` is not available wherever your application is running, then you must either

- Change from scope provided
- Configure that environment to have it available

This of course depends on the technology, as each as their own ways to add libraries to the runtime envrionment.